# Parsing XML file content to a single string in C#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

Hi everyone!

```
<Root>
    <Layers>
        <Layer>
            <LayerName>a</LayerName>
        </Layer>
        <Layer>
            <LayerName>b</LayerName>
        </Layer>
        <Layer>
             <LayerName>c</LayerName>
        </Layer>
    </Layers>
    <Variables>
        <Variable>
            <VariableName>d</VariableName>
        </Variable>
        <Variable>
            <VariableName>e</VariableName>
        </Variable>
        <Variable>
            <VariableName>f</VariableName>
        </Variable>
    </Variables>
</Root>
```

I want to write a code that parses above XML file to a textbox in C#. I want to print layer names and variable names with commas between them. How should i arrange the following code?

```
 private void LoadLayers()
 {
     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
     doc.Load("a1.xml");

     foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//Root/Layers/Layer"))
     {
         string nd = node.SelectSingleNode("LayerName").InnerText;
         textBox1.Text += nd + ",";
     }

     string a = textBox1.Text;
     textBox1.Text = a.Substring(0, a.Length - 1);
 }
```

There can be tags other than variables and layers, i want to be able to get their names too. The result should be like:

a,b,c,d,e,f

Thank you in advance.
PS: English is not my first language so sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: you want to display each variable in separate textbox?

Comment: Can you maybe show us an example of your expected output? It's difficult to understand what you're expecting from your description. Maybe show like you did with a,b,c,d, but dont use letters, use the names from above.

Comment: The result should be like:

a,b,c,d,e,f

Comment: Is the question simply: "How do I get XML nodes by name"?
Because that is a simple question. How you should "arrange your code" Is a matter of opinion and depends on a lot of external criteria.

Comment: i want to write like "a,b,c,d,e,f" in textbox.

Comment: is your xml tree structure always like this even for "other names"? <Root>,<Object><ObjectName>Value</ObjectName></Object></root>?

Comment: Yes always like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Xml Linq with a recursive method :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication19
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonReadXml_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            List<string> output = new List<string>();
            output.Add(root.Name.LocalName);
            RecursiveParse(root, output);
        }
        void RecursiveParse(XElement element, List<string> output)
        {
            if (element.HasElements)
            {
                foreach (XElement newElement in element.Elements())
                {
                    List<string> newOutput = new List<string>(); ;
                    newOutput.AddRange(output);
                    newOutput.Add(newElement.Name.LocalName);
                    RecursiveParse(newElement, newOutput);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                List<string> newOutput = new List<string>();
                newOutput.AddRange(output);
                newOutput.Add((string)element);
                textBox1.Text += string.Join(",", newOutput) + "\r\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I will suggest that you use linq to xml as it is a more modern API for xml parsing.
Here, I got an example based on your provided xml file, that produces your desired output.

Note that this solution is based on the provided xml structure, but you can add element filteing based on nodes naming conventions for a more universal solution.

```
    private void Load_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var xDoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

        //First of all, we want to isolate xml data parsing and result composition. We will store our names in a list.
        List<string> names = new List<string>();

        //Get all tag elements (Layers, Variables)
        foreach (var tag in xDoc.Root.Elements())
        {
            //Get all entries for the tag
            foreach (var entry in tag.Elements())
                //For each entry, we want to get the text of the first child (LayerName, VariableName etc) and add it to our list
                names.Add(entry.Elements().First().Value);
        }

        //Use String.Join to compose collection elements into desired result
        results_textbox.Text = String.Join(",", names);
    }
```

Hope this helps!